# Are XLSForm, ODK XForm and XForms equivalent?

Tags: forms, xforms, odk, odk-xform

I'm currently looking into [XLSForm](https://xlsform.org/), [ODK XForms](https://getodk.github.io/xforms-spec/) and [XForms](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/Forms/wiki/XForms_2.0)

How do these standards compare in terms of functionality and features?

Can they be considered equivalent or are there substantial differences?

Comment: "How do these standards compare in terms of functionality and features?" - have you read through their documentation and done the comparison yourself or not? If not, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ODK](https://getodk.org) is offline data collection software.

[XLSForm](https://xlsform.org) is an Excel-based standard used to design forms for ODK. XLSForms get converted to an ODK XForm, but the process is often hidden from the user.

[ODK XForms](https://getodk.github.io/xforms-spec/) are a subset of W3C XForms used by ODK. They contain a few additional features not found in W3C XForms.

[W3C XForms](https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-xforms-20031014/index.html#contents) were designed to be the successor to HTML forms you find on the web, but no widely used web browser supports XForms.

Answer (score 1):

XForms is a W3C recommendation which is to be used with browsers.